# In a genericDao it is possible not to have n-variables @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to create a CRUD with as little code as possible, based on: Don't repeat the Dao; I have a couple of questions:

1. There is a way to not create a variable for each table in my database: userService, phoneService, n thousand tables
2. If not possible. How could I, from a String, obtain these variables to call the functions of the Dao?

In *Controller*

```
String model = "phone"
Class<?> abc = model+"Service"; ??
Class<?> def = model; ??
abc.read(def, 1);
```

??

**Dao**

```
public interface GenericDao<E, K> {
 public E read(Class<E> type, K id);
}

@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {
 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 @Override
 public E read(Class<E> type, K id) {
  return currentSession().get(type, id);
 }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface GenericService<E, K> {
 public List<E> read(Class<E> type);
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class GenericServiceImpl<E, K> implements GenericService<E, K> {
 @Autowired
 private GenericDao<E, K> dao;
 @Override
 public E read(Class<E> type, K id) {
  return dao.read(type, id);
 }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{model}")
public class CrudController extends Controller {
 @Autowired
 protected GenericService<User, Integer> userService;
 @Autowired
 protected GenericService<Phone, Integer> phoneService;
 @GetMapping("/{id}")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> read(@PathVariable String model, @PathVariable Integer id) {
  Object object = phoneService.read(Phone.class, id);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(object);
 }
}
```

Comment: As your question1. service to meant for business logic , If you have entity class then you can to do curd operation with genericDAO

Comment: I thought i was the only one that did that, i use in a project GenericServiceImpl<AbstractEntity, Integer> instead of GenericServiceImpl<E, K> in my project AbstractEntity is the parent of all entity classes

Comment: Hi, @imperezivan, how to set extends class ...

public interface AdminService extends GenericService<GenericModel, Integer> {
}
<br/>
public class AdminServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<GenericModel, Integer> implements AdminService {

}

(arroba)Autowired
protected AdminService service;

Class<GenericModel> phoneClass = Phone.class; (ERROR:Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Phone> to Class<GenericModel>)

Object phone = service.read(phoneClass, id);

Comment: @temp2010 i copied your code and it works with  GenericServiceImpl<E, K>, have you an exception ?

Comment: Manage to solve it with: Class<GenericModel> genericModel = (Class<GenericModel>) Class.forName("com.app.model." + model);;

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous jobs, I've worked on a `Eclipse RCP` desktop application. It was an ERP, so think about the massive number of database tables it had to deal with, and all the possible parameterizations.

The architecture was completely *generic*, and by that I mean that each *view* based its representation on some *meta-data*. While the approach might seems good at first, it is only so-so. Strong generalization means a lot of compromises in the overall design, generalization means going crazy while debugging, because, well, everything goes through there!
Generalization means going crazy when maintaining the code. What about specific use-cases? You need to handle that some way or another.

The typical web application is not that big, it doesn't deal with hundreds of tables. So don't be scared to repeat the same *Controller - Service - Repository* pattern. That's called separation of concerns, and even encapsulation of data and behaviour.

Keep your packages well organized and everything will be fine.